# Fade Inline-Block with CSS and Velocity JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [Velocity JS](http://velocityjs.org/) to fade a list object.

The problem is that Velocity applies **display: list-item; opacity: 1;** to the element and overrides my **display: inline-block;** and my list is now vertical.

How can I force it to always use inline-block?

https://jsfiddle.net/01qvqmxa/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".myList li").velocity("fadeIn", { delay: 300, duration: 2000 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `!important` notation:

```
li {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/01qvqmxa/1/)